# How to collect a NodeJS app's logs (using PM2) so that they can be queried in Azure Monitor?

Tags: node.js, azure, pm2, kql

Since Azure is moving away from Log Analytics,
we want to have this implemented directly using Azure Monitor.
Azure monitor agent for linux is already in place, so the question is how to use the existing PM2 logs (out, and error) in order to be able to create meaningful metrics and alerts based on these
(eg. with KQL)

ps: new to Azure

Tried implementing this using Log Analytics agent but since this will be deprecated soon,
I'm switching to Azure Monitor.
So far not much is implemented in that direction

Answer (score 0):

I deployed one node.js Application inside the Linux VM like below:-

My **node.js code**:-

```js
// app.js
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello, world!');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

***Created one app.js file and added this code inside it like below:-***

[image]

Started my node.js app on Linux VM like below:-

**Command:-**

```js
node app.js
```

[image]

I installed Pm2 and ran my nodejs application with Pm2 like below:-

**Command:-**

```bash
sudo npm install -g pm2
```

**Run the app with pm2:-**

```bash
pm2 start app.js
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**Got Pm2 logs like below:-**

```
pm2 logs
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Now, Visited my Log analytics workspace and added my VM in the Monitoring agent  by creating a Data collection rule like below:-

[image]

Add Data source with the below code:-

```
\root\.pm2\logs\*.log
```

[image]

Added the Linux  syslogs and Performance counter like below:-

[image]

The Linux syslog only writes the below options:-

[image]

And Performance counters are used to get Linux VM's metrics like below:-

[image]

I also tried adding custom pm2 log file oath in performance counter but it did not write the pm2 logs in Log analytics table, refer below:-

[image]

Both options does not include any custom method to include pm2 logs. As an alternative you can open your log file in your Linux VM and then copy it to your local machine and create a custom table in Log analytics with Pm2 logs like below:-

**Command :-**

```bash
nano app-error.log
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can also create custom table with Data collection rule by selecting Custom as a platform like below:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
I ended up using a simple REST call to 

https://${logsWorkspaceId}.ods.opinsights.azure.com/api/logs?api-version=${logsVersion}

Btw, does your pm2 work with log rotation? Cause if it does, it might cause some issues (overwriting log files, etc)